# Why debootstrap can only run as root?

Tags: debian, non-root-user, debian-installer, debootstrap

I want to download Debian system using `debootstrap` (creating chroot environment) and when I run `debootstrap stable ./dir $debian_ftp`, `debootstrap` says:

```
E: debootstrap can only run as root
```

Why can't `debootstrap` be run without root permissions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to be able to create a chroot when you use `debootstrap`. Plus if you plan on partitioning, or doing any mounts, etc. you will need root permissions.

If you check out the [debootstrap manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/debootstrap/debootstrap.8.en.html) you should be able to use `debootstrap` with the `--variant=fakechroot` option to use `fakechroot`, which installs the packages without root privileges. An example in your case would be something along the lines of this:

```
debootstrap --variant=fakechroot stable ./dir $debian_ftp
```

Please read the [Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) for more information on how to use `debootstrap`.

Comment: Small addition: `debootstap` creates device nodes as well, which also requires root permissions, but that part can be faked by `fakeroot`.

Comment: I think you need to wrap debootstrap call with `fakechroot fakeroot` for it to work